# Using SQL concat and coalesce to display when values are null

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, coalesce

I have the following table.  city, state, and zipcode are all varchar type and can be NULL.

```
MyContacts
-id (int PK)
-city (varchar null)
-state (varchar null)
-zipcode (varchar null)
```

I would like to return city, state, and zipcode formatted as a single value as follows:

```
Seattle WA 98423 if all are not NULL
Seattle WA if zip is NULL
Seattle 98423 if state is NULL
WA 98423 if city is NULL
Seattle if state and zip is NULL
WA if city and zip is NULL
98423 if city and state is NULL
NULL if all of them are NULL
```

I have been trying something like the following, but think I am going about it wrong.  Thanks

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(city," ",state," ",zipcode),CONCAT(city," ",states),zipcode) AS location
```

Comment: Ah, looks like I have it backwards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(city,state,zip_code) IS NOT NULL
THEN
    TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(IFNULL(city,""),
                   " ",
                   IFNULL(state,""),
                   " ",
                   IFNULL(zip code,"")),
            "  "," "))
ELSE
    NULL
END
```

OR
`CONCAT_WS` already handles NULL effectively, so we don't need a NULL check inside it.

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(city,state,zip_code) IS NOT NULL
THEN
    CONCAT_WS(' ',city,
                  state,
                  zipcode) 
ELSE
    NULL
END AS location
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',COALESCE(city,''),COALESCE(state,''),COALESCE(zipcode,'')) AS location
```

Comment: Emtpy space + space gives a additional space left.

Comment: @OracleUser  Agreed.  I am probably okay with that, but it doesn't answer the question since the query said it should return NULL like yours will.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(city , '', state, '', zipcode), CONCAT(city, '', state), zipcode) AS location from MyContacts;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).